# JButton leaving artifacts in JPanel after being removed?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I have to create a `JLabel` and a `JButton`, put them into a `JPanel`, and then display it all in a `JFrame`. The `JButton` must be removed and the `JLabel`'s text changed upon clicking the `JButton`. It all works fine, except for one thing: When the button is removed from the `JPanel`, it still leaves an artifact of itself. Here's my code, try it for yourself:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new TestClass();
    }

    public TestClass()
    {
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel jlabel = new JLabel ("-->");
        JButton jbutton = new JButton ("Click here!");

        jbutton.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
            {
                jlabel.setText ("Good job!");
                jpanel.remove (jbutton);
            }
        });

        jpanel.add (jlabel);
        jpanel.add (jbutton);

        JFrame jframe = new JFrame ("Test Frame");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setSize (340, 60);
        jframe.setResizable (false);
        jframe.add (jpanel);
        jframe.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: If "the `JButton` must be removed" means you just don't want the `JButton` visible, I think it would be better to just do `jbutton.setVisible(false)`  instead of calling `remove`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove a Swing component, you should call `revalidate()` then `repaint()` on its container:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    jlabel.setText("Good job!");
    jpanel.remove(jbutton);
    jpanel.revalidate();
    jpanel.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jlabel.setText ("Good job!");
jbutton.setVisible (false);
jpanel.remove (jbutton);
jpanel.repaint();
```

This redraws the panel after removing it, and sets the visibility off.